# Entity frameworks support for mysql? Any performance issues?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I was reading on another question a few days ago that EF now supports mysql, is this correct?

Someone was saying they tried using it but performance was really bad.

Is this true?  Has anyone tried it out?  Does it support all the features of ms sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use EF with MySQL, You will need a MySQL provider, one is devarts' here: http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/

EF adds an extra layer, so it will be slower than accessing the database directly, assuming that the person writing the query can write a query as good as that which the provider generates.

There, have been some performance problems reported, but you can always override the generated SQL if you need to. http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,425483,425483#msg-425483